# Mocked method not working in golang while running the test cases

Tags: go, go-testing

I am trying to mock an struct method in test cases but it is not working.
I want to mock **Validate** method here:
`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type DemoInterface interface {
    Inc(int) (int, error)
    Validate(int) error
}
type DemoStruct struct{}

func (l DemoStruct) Inc(num int) (int, error) {
    err := l.Validate(num)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    num = num + 100
    return num, nil

}
func (l DemoStruct) Validate(num int) error {// SOME DB LOGIC IS HERE WHICH I CAN NOT POST at Stackoverflow
    if num > 100 {
        return fmt.Errorf("INVALID NUM %v", num)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    s, err := DemoStruct{}.Inc(10)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

`

My test cases:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

const (
    SUCCESS = "SUCCESS"
    ERROR   = "ERROR"
)

type MockDemoStruct struct {
    DemoStruct
    functionality string
}

func (m MockDemoStruct) Validate(num int) error {
    switch m.functionality {
    case SUCCESS:
        return nil
    case ERROR:
        fmt.Errorf("MOCK ERROR %v", num)

    }
    return fmt.Errorf("MOCK ERROR %v", num)
}

func TestPath(t *testing.T) {

    t.Run("ERROR", func(t *testing.T) {
        ls := MockDemoStruct{DemoStruct{}, ERROR}
        res, err := ls.Inc(110)
        expected := fmt.Errorf("MOCK ERROR %v", 10)
        if err != expected {
            t.Errorf("NOT MATCH  %v  %v", err, expected)
            //NOT MATCH  INVALID NUM 110  MOCK ERROR 10

        }
        fmt.Println(res)
    })
}
```

Here **MockDemoStruct.Validate** is not being called.
I am getting **INVALID NUM 110** from  Validate, but it should be **MOCK ERROR 110**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the method mockable we will have to use a DI(dependency injection) based code pattern.

```
**We can mock only those methods which are injectable**.
```

We have two options to introduce **dependency injection** in this code.

1. Use Delegation Design pattern with the help of  interface
2. Introduce Monkey patching using the function as a type

**Delegation using interface:**

```
type Deligation interface {
    Validate(num int) error
}

type DemoStruct struct {
    delegate Deligation
}

func (DemoStruct) Validate(num int) error {
    if num > 100 {
        return fmt.Errorf("INVALID NUM %v", num)
    }
    return nil
}
func (l DemoStruct) Inc(num int) (int, error) {
    err := l.delegate.Validate(num) // Call method using delegate
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    num = num + 100
    return num, nil

}

func main() {
    s, err := DemoStruct{delegate: DemoStruct{}}.Inc(10) // assign delegate inside DemoStruct
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

Using Monkey patching:

```
func Validate(num int) error {
    if num > 100 {
        return fmt.Errorf("INVALID NUM %v", num)
    }
    return nil
}

type DemoStruct struct {
    Validate func(num int) error //  function as a type
}

func (l DemoStruct) Inc(num int) (int, error) {
    err := l.Validate(num)// It can be replaced in test cases.
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    num = num + 100
    return num, nil

}

func main() {
    s, err := DemoStruct{Validate: Validate}.Inc(10) // assign Validate inside DemoStruct
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

Ref: https://blog.myhro.info/2018/06/how-to-mock-golang-methods

Answer (score 1):

In this case the method `Inc` in the `DemoStruct` calls the method `l.Validate` where l is a `DemoStruct`. The reciever of that method is explicitly a `DemoStruct`. So the `MockDemoStruct.Validate` method will not be called.

Go does not have inheritance as you assumed here in your code. You can not override the method of the `DemoStruct`. The `MockDemoStruct` composes the `DemoStruct`. To actually test this method, I suggest passing the `DemoStruct` a db interface, which can be mocked in your test.

Comment: thanks for your comment,  Can you suggest some code restructure that can enable  the mocking of  Validate method with num > 100  logic only

Comment: If you create an interface for your db interaction you can pass  that interface to your `DemoStruct`. In your test you can then mock the database interaction so that you can only test the `num > 100` logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to implement 'Inc' receiver for 'MockDemoStruct', here you trying to overuse the inheritance property of struct, looks like GO doesn't support that.